# Como verificar se último item foi registrado hoje?

Tags: sqlite

Tenho uma seguinte tabela:

```
+----+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| id |     description       |       created_at      |
+----+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| 5  | Game Of Thrones       |  2017-03-14 17:45:12  |
| 4  | Breaking Bad          |  2017-03-13 13:45:12  |
| 3  | Vikings               |  2017-03-12 12:45:12  |
| 2  | How I Met Your Mother |  2017-03-10 18:45:12  |
| 1  | Mr. Robot             |  2017-03-09 11:45:12  |
+----+-----------------------+ ----------------------+
```

Criação da tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable(
   int INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   description TEXT,
   created_at  DATETIME)
```

Esta table é incrementada todo dia num horário aleatório. Gostaria de uma *query* que verifica se já foi registrado um novo item no dia de hoje. Neste caso ai ainda não teria registro pois hoje é `2017-03-15 11:14:22`, então eu poderia registrar um novo item.

Tendo em vista que é possível pegar o último item registrado usando a query:

```
select * from myTable order by created_at desc limit 1
```

Como poderia verificar se esse se o último item foi registrado hoje baseado na hora atual?

Comment: @AckLay, fazendo um max no id, não resolvee?

Comment: tente assim select description from myTable where created_at = datetime()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu faria assim:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    myTable
WHERE
    strftime ('%Y-%m-%d', created_at) = strftime ('%Y-%m-%d', 'now')
ORDER BY
    created_at DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Usando o `STRFTIME(Format, Field)` para formatar a data.
Se for igual vai retornar o registro.

Comment: Uma vez eu tentei usar o now() no sqlite e não funcionou. Ver ver novamente aqui e te falo.

Comment: De fato, ocorreu novamente o erro: `no such function: now`

Comment: Era só `'now'`.

Comment: não testei com o 'now' mas criei uma função que faz o mesmo propósito do 'now' e funcionou certinho. Obrigado +1

Answer (score 0):

Você pode consultar a data de hoje utilizando o comando `BETWEEN`.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM myTable
WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2017-03-15 00:00:00' AND '2017-03-15 23:59:59'
```

Isso vai trazer os registros que já foram inseridos hoje.
Se você quiser que a consulta descubra a data automáticamente, pode usar a seguinte:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM myTable
WHERE created_at BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00', NOW()) AND DATE_FORMAT('%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59', NOW())
```